# How to dowload a file (blob) which is Int8Array in Angular

Tags: java, sql-server, angular, download, blob

I am trying to download a file in Angular. The file is saved in db as varbinary. Java REST service fetched it as byte[]. I am having it as Int8Array in Angular. However when I download it I beleive it is base64 encoded

```
      const link = document.createElement( 'a' );
      link.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild( link );

      const blob = new Blob([myFileByteArray], {type: 'text/xlsx'});  //myFile is Int8Array 
      const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
    
      link.href = objectURL;
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download =  this.myfile.name;
      link.click();
```

This is how it is in MSSQL: `0x323032312D30392D323720303 ...`
And this is how it is when I download this xlsx and open it: `MjAyMS0wOS0yNyAwNzozMDsxMi4wODI7bT`

I beleive it is base64 encoded somewhere in that path from sql to browser...I saved it in a SQL like this `'CAST('this is my xslx' AS VARBINARY (MAX))` so I know it should be this text.

Comment: Have you tried base64 decoding it then? I know I've seen Microsoft APIs base64 encode data like this (when using Newtonsoft.Json or System.Text.Json on .NET/Core) because JSON doesn't allow embedding of binary literals. base64 encoding only expands the binary data by 33%, whereas the alternative would be sending a `number` array which could be 400% larger in the worst case.

Comment: I copied this base64 string which I send from Java REST as byte[] to Angular where it is Int8Array to online converter and I can confirm that this is my csv file. I just don't know who implicitly encoded it? In Angular I am returning this `return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url + '/get-file?id=' + id);` Could it be that this conversion does HttpClient? From Java I am returning result as ResponseEntity. Is it ResponseEntity's fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change a type in Angular from Int8Array to string and then I could use atob() method to decode from base64. I just don't know why is it in base64. Could it be because I use Spring Boot ResponseEntity ...

```
      this.myFile= this.myFileResultSet.result;
      let myFileByteArray = this.myFile.myFileBytes //before Int8Array, now String
      console.log(myFileByteArray);

      let myFileDecoded = atob(myFileByteArray); // must be string not Int8Array to be able to 
                                                     // convert it from base64 
      const link = document.createElement( 'a' );
      link.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild( link );

      const blob = new Blob([myFileDecoded], {type: 'text/csv'});
      const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
    
      link.href = objectURL;
      link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download =  this.myFile.name;
      link.click();
    });
```